# Why the job tasks of an AWS EMR job are executed in sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I uploaded a customer jar to the S3, and wanted to run the job in EMR.
So in the cluster config, I selected 1 master, and two workers, specified the jar path, input path and output path. Everything was fine.

Once it started to run the customer jar, I found I couldn't view job tasks, cause it told me "no tasks available", which was very strange. And after the job was done, I found that the emr created 306 tasks in total, but when I looked into the syslog of each task, I found that they were all executed in sequence. For example, maptask260 finishes at 19:40:35, and maptask261 started from 19:40:40, and maptask262 started after 261 was done.

I understand that EMR create a bunch of tasks according to the job size, and I think all the tasks should be executed in parallel, which means, as soon as the job started to be run, it should create, say 360 tasks, and all the tasks should start to work at the same time.

Not sure whether I'm wrong in my understanding or I mis-configured something?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The tasks should run in parallel in EMR, but you only started 2 workers and you didn't specify which instance type. If you have 306 tasks and you want all of them to run in parallel you'll probably want to start more than 2.

For instance, with Hadoop 1 on EMR, you get 8 mapper slots on m1.xlarge instances. To run 306 tasks in parallel you'll have to start 39 m1.xlarge machines.

I'm not sure if that's what you want, because you'll pay for a whole hour per machine, even if the map-reduce job executes for 5 minutes.

Comment: I launched two m1.medium instances. It was only for testing purpose, so I didn't use two many workers... But even if two instances are not enough for 306 tasks to be run in parallel, at least it should get 2 or 3 tasks run at the same time... (in my personal understanding)...why all the tasks were executed in sequence? so confusing...

Comment: If you had more than 1 available slot, the mapper tasks (or reducer tasks) in a map/reduce job should run in parallel.